# Is there a way to mock/stub "puts" in Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, testing

I am printing some custom messages in my application using the puts command. However, I do not want these to be appearing in my Test Output. So, I tried a way to stub `puts` as shown below. But it still outputs my messages. What am I doing wrong ?

```
stubs(:puts).returns("") #Did not work out
Object.stubs(:puts).returns("") #Did not work out either
puts.stubs.returns "" #Not working as well
Kernel.stubs(:puts).returns "" #No luck
```

I am using `Test::Unit`

Comment: Try stubbing [Kernel#puts](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-puts) instead.

Comment: @CodeGnome : Still no luck , see updated question

Comment: I don't know why stubbing not works in your case, but overriding puts completely works:

```ruby

> Kernel.send(:define_method, :puts) do "" end
 => #<Proc:0xb771fd38@(irb):2> 
> puts "foobar"
 => "" 
```

Although in general, results might be strange, if your testing framework should use puts as well for output.

Comment: Have you tried stubbing `$stdout.puts`?

Answer (score 7):

You probably need to stub it on the actual instance that calls `puts`. E.g. if you're calling `puts` in an instance method of a `User` class, try:

```
user = User.new
user.stubs(:puts)
user.some_method_that_calls_puts
```

This similarly applies to when you're trying to test `puts` in the top-level execution scope:

```
self.stubs(:puts)
```

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is define a custom log method (that essentially calls puts for now) which you can mock or silence in test quite easily.

This also gives you the option later to do more with it, like log to a file.

edit: Or if you really want to stub puts, and you are calling it inside an instance method for example, you can just stub puts on the instance of that class.

Answer (score 1):

Using Rails 5 + Mocha: `$stdout.stubs(puts: '')`

Answer (score 0):

So the comments to the original post point to the answer:

```
Kernel.send(:define_method, :puts) { |*args| "" }
```

Instead of silencing all output, I would only silence output from the the particular objects that are putsing during your tests.

```
class TestClass
  def some_method
    ...
    puts "something"
  end
end

it "should do something expected" do
  TestClass.send(:define_method, :puts) { |*args| "" }
  test_class.some_method.should == "abc123"
end
```